# "Page number 1 to 4 are torn"

Tags: word-choice

If my exercise book is numbered on every page, which sentence should I use if the first two sheets are torn?

> 1. **Page number** 1 to 4 are torn.
> 2. **Page numbers** 1 to 4 are torn.
> 3. **Pages numbers** 1 to 4 are torn.
> 4. **Pages number** 1 to 4 are torn.

Comment: Try "Pages 1 to 4 are torn." Lose the "number(s)", you don't need it.

Comment: Robusto's answer is right. But if you really, *really* want to get "number" into your sentence, the best I can think of is "The pages numbered 1 to 4 are torn."

Comment: "Page numbers 1 *through* 4 are torn."  Eliminate the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

"Pages 1 to 4 are torn" as Robusto said. However, it got me thinking. If you tore out the pages, you would only say you tore out two pages; a page can be a side or the entire leaf. So you could say "Pages 1 and 3 are torn."

Comment: Thanks, Robusto and Steve. It would appear it would be impossible to include 'number' in that sentence.

Comment: Not impossible: just unnecessary.